# write a file till a limit size of 1474560(floppy disk)

Tags: java

So i need to make a code that will make the size of a text,pdf,jpg,... till
or equal to 1474560(size of a floppy disk).The question is how to make this limitation so the writeFile will stop till 1474560 size.

```
void newFileParser(String initialPath, String finalPath){
        try{
            FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(finalPath,true);
            File newfile = new File(finalPath);

            while(newfile.length()  < 1474560){
                writeFile.write("0\n");
            }
            writeFile.close();
            if(newfile.length() <= 1474560){
                System.out.println("New file is done");
            }
            System.out.println("The size of the NewFile: " + newfile.length());
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXpem.png)

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: my output file size is bigger then it must be

Comment: Seems like you are writing two bytes, so if you starting file is of an odd size, you will end up with an off by 1 error.

Comment: If i have a empty file then it work fine but if i put a jpg file or pdf file then it goes over the limit of 1474560

Comment: What is the point of all of this? Assume your file has 2_500_000 bytes? Is the intention that any byte after 1_474_560 gets thrown away?

Answer (score 2):

You use the `FileWriter` which buffers the output. This means that the `newFile.length()` may return not the amount of bytes that you wrote, but the amount of bytes currently flushed to the disk.

Just use a loop with a specific amount of iterations. And remember to either close the writer in the `finally` clause, or use `try-with-resources`, as below:

```java
void newFileParser(String initialPath, String finalPath) {
    File newfile = new File(finalPath);
    long initialLength = 0;
    if (newfile.exists()) {
        initialLength = newfile.length();
    }
    try (FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(finalPath, true)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1474560 - initialLength; i++) {
            writeFile.write(0);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("The size of the NewFile: " + newfile.length());
}
```

Comment: @VadimDoga I'm pretty sure the code works on a new file. If you need to run it on an existing file, you should reduce the number of iterations by the initial length of the file. I've updated the code.